# Pacman can't find virtualbox-host-modules-arch anywhere - Always 404

Tags: linux, virtualbox, arch-linux, dependencies

Trying to install VirtualBox, but pacman cannot find the **virtualbox-host-modules-arch** package, every mirror pacman tries gets a 404:

```
resolving dependencies...
:: There are 2 providers available for VIRTUALBOX-HOST-MODULES:
:: Repository community
   1) virtualbox-host-dkms  2) virtualbox-host-modules-arch

Enter a number (default=1): 2
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (2) virtualbox-host-modules-arch-5.2.2-7  virtualbox-5.2.2-2

Total Download Size:     0.20 MiB
Total Installed Size:  102.95 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] 
:: Retrieving packages...
error: failed retrieving file 'virtualbox-host-modules-arch-5.2.2-7-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from arch.mirror.square-r00t.net : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'virtualbox-host-modules-arch-5.2.2-7-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from arch.mirror.square-r00t.net : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'virtualbox-host-modules-arch-5.2.2-7-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from arch.mirror.square-r00t.net : Protocol "rsync" not supported or disabled in libcurl
error: failed retrieving file 'virtualbox-host-modules-arch-5.2.2-7-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from archlinux.prometeolibero.eu : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'virtualbox-host-modules-arch-5.2.2-7-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from archlinux.prometeolibero.eu : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'virtualbox-host-modules-arch-5.2.2-7-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from arch.mirror.square-r00t.net : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'virtualbox-host-modules-arch-5.2.2-7-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from arch.mirror.square-r00t.net : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'virtualbox-host-modules-arch-5.2.2-7-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from arch.mirror.square-r00t.net : Protocol "rsync" not supported or disabled in libcurl
error: failed retrieving file 'virtualbox-host-modules-arch-5.2.2-7-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from archlinux.prometeolibero.eu : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'virtualbox-host-modules-arch-5.2.2-7-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' from archlinux.prometeolibero.eu : The requested URL returned error: 404
```

Is this because the virtualbox-host-modules-arch package in the repo is actually version 5.2.2-10 ?  And if so, how do I use that as the dependency?

Answer (score 3):

> Is this because the virtualbox-host-modules-arch package in the repo is actually version 5.2.2-10?

Yes.

> And if so, how do I use that as the dependency?

Tell pacman to refresh the local copy of repository information.

This could be done using `pacman -Sy`, but it's *strongly* recommended to perform a full system upgrade using **`pacman -Syu`** instead.